# Obtaining posteriors for exclusive and exhaustive hypotheses

Tags: bayesian, bayes

I'm trying to solve a Bayesian problem where I have two mutually exclusive and exhaustive hypotheses: $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Given Baye's formula:

$$P(H|D) = \frac{P(H)P(D|H)}{P(D)}$$

(where $D$ is my data) I've [read](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/html/thinkbayes002.html) that one way to obtain the posteriors $P(H_1|D)$ and $P(H_2|D)$, is to create a table like this one:

```
      P(H) (prior) | P(D|H) (Likelihood) |
    ____________________________________________________
H1 |      P(H1)    |        L(H1)        | P(H1)*L(H1)
H2 |      P(H2)    |        L(H2)        | P(H2)*L(H2)
```

Then summing the values in the third column I get the *normalization constant* $P(D)$ as:

$$P(D) = P(H_1)L(H_1) + P(H_2)L(H_2)$$

which yields for each hypothesis the posteriors as:

$$P(H_1|D) = \frac{P(H_1)L(H_1)}{P(H_1)L(H_1) + P(H_2)L(H_2)}$$
$$P(H_2|D) = \frac{P(H_2)L(H_2)}{P(H_1)L(H_1) + P(H_2)L(H_2)}$$

My knowledge in statistics is not much and I haven't been able to confirm this anywhere else. Could someone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: I  can confirm. It is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

From the *Law of Total Probability* and then the definition of *conditional probability*:
$$
P(D) = \sum_{H_i} P(D, H_i) = \sum_{H_i} P(D \mid H_i) P(H_i).
$$
And finally from *Bayes Theorem*:
$$
P(H_j \mid D) = \frac{P(D \mid H_j)P(H_j) }{P(D)} = \frac{ P(D \mid H_j)P(H_j)}{\sum_{H_i} P(D \mid H_i)P(H_i)}.
$$
Of course, keep in mind that the likelihood of a hypothesis is given by
$$
L(H_j) = P(D \mid H_j).
$$